# How to add Total on RDLC multi group ie..cell is grouped in row wise as well as column wise:

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

IT will be expand when running in ssrs,i am trying to add total its show wrong total.
The Query I am Trying:

```
SELECT MTime,CDate ,MNAME,MemNo,Liters, FAT, SNF, MRate, Amount
FROM tblCowMilk INNER JOIN
     TBLMEMBERS
     ON tblCowMilk.MemNo = TBLMEMBERS.MNO
WHERE CDate '2016-02-01' Between '2016-02-10' and
group by MNAME,MTime,MemNo,CDate,Liters, FAT, SNF, MRate, Amount
```

See the ssrs Designing Tablix Before Running in rdlc:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0c4p.png)

After running See this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsMb4.png)

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct so it should return an error.

Comment: Please Tell Me how to do it....